# react-native default scene showing back button, but not from Action.SceneName({ back: true })

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have an app where i am using react-native-router-flux.
If i am showing a specific scene as default scene, and passing

```
<Scene key="FEEDBACK_SCENE" backButtonTintColor={'black'} component={FeedbackScene} navigationBarStyle={styles.NavbarStyle} title={FEEDBACK_SCENE_TITLE} titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle} back={false} />
```

if i am using it like this, its not showing back button on the navbar of that Feedback scene.

But from some other scene if i am trying to go to Feedback scene, and passing `Action.FEEDBACK_SCENE({ back: true }),` but still its not showing the back button.

But if i am doing `console.log(this.props)` its shwoing the new props called on Actions.FEEDBACK_SCENE({ back: true })

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the scene with the new prop.

Try

```
Actions.FEEDBACK_SCENE({
    refresh : { back: true }
})
```